# Package documentation not available on Void Linux

Tags: packages, linux

Previously I used Windows, Ubuntu, and MX Linux operating systems. On that operating system I can read and download LaTeX package documentation in TeXLive in .pdf format. Now, I use the Seventh Heaven operating system based on Void Linux. And I didn't find any package documentation on that distro. Is it true that the package documentation is not in the Void Linux repository or is there an incomplete setting in the operating system that I am currently using. Here is a picture when I search for package documentation on console.
[image]

Comment: How did you install TeX?  TeXLive includes the documentation by default, but it's possible to have left it out.

Comment: According to the instructions in the distro documentation. I typed the command in the console : get texlive-full

Comment: @AanTriono The texlive versions packaged for linux are often not up-to-date. Better install a vanilla texlive from tug.org. As an additional benefit this allows you to decide during the installation if the docs should be installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like void [uses the arch TeX Live distribution](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/blob/master/srcpkgs/texlive-core/template), the TeX Live packaged by arch [doesn't include documentation with its packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#Package_documentation).

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: Not having doumentation, as default, may be good. For example, Arch Linux can be installed as a `proot` (restricted) subsystem in Android devices. Such devices often do not have a hard drive, or a great deal of on-board storage. Bett to save space by downloading only the docs you need to read, one by one.

Comment: @rallg sure, the TUG installer can omit documentation, as can MiKTeX, but there doesn't seem to be any centrally packaged documentation, all that's offered is a single rather out-of-date dump in AUR or the option to manually and locally install individual documentation.